How do I solve a "cannot resolve module 'ballerina/regex' " error in ballerina
I get the following error when trying to use regex in Ballerina using the ballerina/regex module:
cannot resolve module 'ballerina/regex'

I’ve tried importing the ballerina/regex, but the error persists.
Here's my code:
function extractContentDispositionParams(string contentDisposition) returns map<string> {
    map<string> params = {};
    string[] parts = regex:split(contentDisposition, ";");

    foreach string part in parts {
        string[] keyValue = regex:split(part.trim(), "=");
        if (keyValue.length() == 2) {
            string key = keyValue[0].trim();
            string value = keyValue[1].trim().replace("\"", "");
            params[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return params;
}

How can I resolve this error? Is there a different package I should be using, or am I doing something wrong?

With the given info, I am assuming the error occurs since the regex module is no longer packed with the Ballerina distribution, which is likely causing the issue (when running the commands with the --offline flag).
And also the ballerina/regex module has been deprecated, and the recommended replacement is the ballerina/lang.regexp module.
You can update your code as here to use the new regexp module.
function extractContentDispositionParams(string contentDisposition) returns map<string>|error {
    map<string> params = {};
    string[] parts = regexp:split(re `;`, contentDisposition);
    foreach string part in parts {
        string[] keyValue = regexp:split(re `=`, part.trim());
        if (keyValue.length() == 2) {
            string key = keyValue[0].trim();
            string value = keyValue[1].trim();
            regexp:RegExp regexValue = check regexp:fromString(value);
            params[key] = regexValue.replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return params;
}


import ballerina/lang.regexp;

function extractContentDispositionParams(string contentDisposition) returns map<string> {
    map<string> params = {};
    string[] parts = regexp:split(re `;`, contentDisposition);

    foreach string part in parts {
        string[] keyValue = regexp:split(re `=`, part.trim());
        if (keyValue.length() == 2) {
            string key = keyValue[0].trim();
            string value = re `"`.replace(keyValue[1].trim(), "");
            params[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return params;
}

You can learn more about Ballerina regex in here.
https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/regexp-type/
https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/latest
